# Influence of Schwarzschild radius and event horizon of ordinary objects

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, causality

As far as I know, every body (with mass) has a Schwarzschild radius and therefore an event horizon. Thus, take an orange with radius $R$ and mass $M$ for example, then the Schwarzschild radius is given by:
$$R_S = \frac{2 G M}{c^2}$$
but what happens when I cross this radius let's say by cutting it in half with a knife?

And in the orange, are there particles that do not experience moving time?

And what happens inside this pretty small but existing inner ball (inside the event horizon)?

Thinking about these questions, it seems counterintuitive to be so, but using the physics the way I understand them, it does make sense.
I hope somebody can point out my logical error.

P.S.: I am new to physics and just a little bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you calculate the Schwarzschild radius $R_S$ of your orange, then you have the radius of the event horizon if there was a black hole with the mass of your orange. It has nothing to do with your orange itself.

Your orange is not a black hole and its radius R is considerably larger than the Schwarzschild radius of a black hole of the same mass, $R >> R_S$.

There is no event horizon inside your orange and you also cannot cut it in half, i.e. nothing spectacular will happen, unfortunately.

When people calculate "the Schwarzschild radius of an everyday object", then this is done merely to get an intuitive understanding to what incredibly small size you have to compress something if you wanted to turn it into a black hole: if you compressed your orange into a ball with radius $R_S = \frac{2G M_{orange}}{c^2} = 3\times 10^{-28} m$ (if your orange weighs $M = 200g$), it would be a black hole.

Compare this to the size of an atomic nucleus, whose radius is of the order of $\approx 10^{-15}m$, to see how small your orange would need to be in order to turn into a black hole.

Comment: As far as I understand, the Schwarzschild radius characterizes the warping of the space-time itself caused by an object/mass.
According to your answer, it seems to me that only black holes have a Schwarzschild radius and therefore lead to a warping of the time (like time-dilation). However, this counters my knowledge that the gravitational field of the sun, earth or other mass-like object lead to different ticking clocks in respect to the distance to this. That is, that in close proximity to the sun, photons get deccelerated (or rather as they keep on going with $c$, time slows down for them)

Comment: The warping of spacetime, or in other words, the curvature, exists also without a Schwarzschild radius or a black hole.

Comment: You're right in saying that objects like the Sun cause a curvature in the spacetime around it and this leads to clocks ticking differently. Also the orange will cause some curvature but of course a dramatically smaller one. -- A Schwarzschild radius is a property of a black hole only: it is the radius of the event horizon. Inside and outside the event horizon, the geometry of spacetime is fundamentally different. But also without event horizon, you can have curvature.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I get it <3

Comment: Ordinary objects *do* have a Schwarzschild radius, but they don't have an event horizon. Of course, $R_s$ is ridiculously tiny for something like an orange, but for things like planets & stars it's quite handy if you want to calculate gravitational time dilation in their vicinity. Eg, for Earth $R_s\approx 8.870056$ mm.

Answer (score 3):

The Schwarzschild radius as an event horizon only applies if all the mass is interior to that radial coordinate. Thus your orange does not have an event horizon at its centre.

In other circumstances, the Schwarzschild radius is simply a parameter that appears in the Schwarzschild metric, which applies *outside* any static, spherically symmetric mass distribution.

It is useful, because GR effects will become strong as the radial coordinate of a body approaches the Schwarzschild radius. i.e. When we cannot assume that $r \gg r_s$. Of course for objects other than black holes the surface of the object is encountered before something can get very close to the Schwarzschild radius.